# how do i add gradient fill across text in gimp

Tags: gimp

how do i add gradient fill across text in gimp

[image]

Comment: Right click the text layer and choose Alpha to Selection, then use the gradient tool.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of ways...

The simplest is to set the  alpha-lock on the text layer and draw the gradient across it (without any selection, the alpha-lock will ensure that all pixels keep their opacity). However this makes the text layer a plain layer, so you can no longer edit it.

The next level is to use `Layer > Transparency > Alpha to selection`, add a layer, and create the gradient on that new layer (bound by the selection). You can then hide the text layer. But if you edit the text layer, you have to redo the whole thing.

The boss level is to create a layer group with two layers: the gradient layer at the top, and the text layer under it, and use the layer properties dialog to set the gradient layer to `Composite mode: Clip to backdrop`. You can then edit the text and the gradient separately, in a completely instant WYSIWYG manner without having to redo anything:

[image]